# Make sure that all the items emitted by a hot observable are consumed exactly once

Tags: rx-java

I have:

1. A source that is a hot observable that at some point emits one item
   and completes
2. Multiple observers that keep subscribing/unsubscribing
   to/from the source (but at most one can be subscribed at the same
   time)

I would like to transform the source to an observable that makes sure the item is consumed **exactly once** by an observer. Observers that subscribe later should be only notified that the item has been consumed (completion event).

Expected behaviour:

1) Emission from the source before an observer subscribes

```
--O-|------>  (source)

-----^-O-|->  (observer)
```

2) Emission from the source after an observer subscribes

```
------O-|->  (source)

--^---O-|->  (observer)
```

3) Subscription after item has been consumed

```
-O-|------->  (source)

-^-O-|----->  (observer1 - consumes the item)

------^-|-->  (observer2 - is notified that the item has been consumed)
```

What is the simplest and most elegant way to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BehaviorSubject`. This describes its behavior exactly.

Comment: Oh, it seems I misunderstood how the BehaviorSubject works. You're right, it solves the problem perfectly! Thanks!